# Step request in VS Code extension not rendering correctly

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am working on an extension/debugger and I am having a problem with step debugging. I have implemented the `nextRequest` method in my debug adapter and it calls my internal debugger to initiate the step request, then returns the response. I have an event handler that gets notified when the step request is processed and this in turn sends a `StoppedEvent` of type `step` to VS Code.

The problem I have is that VS Code reacts to the `StoppedEvent` by requesting the threads and the stack frames, but it does not render the "stopped" indicator (yellow arrow) at all, so the user has no visual indication that the step succeeded (other than the yellow arrow from the breakpoint disappearing). I'm thinking VS Code may not be getting the right file or line number, but I checked that these are set correctly in the frames I return in the response to `stackTraceRequest`. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0):

This was my mistake. The paths sent were being computed slightly differently form the paths sent at breakpoint events, which is why it worked for breakpoints but not for step events.